# Spring Web MVC Environment @Autowired To Get Only System Property throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, environment-variables

I'm using `Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE` and I got **NO** properties file, just in case I want to set some runtime variables by `System.setProperty()` and then get it by Spring via Environment variable, but it says Environment variable is `null`. As below in one of my `@Component` class I'm using a variable. And before that I set a system property from somewhere else.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue.
`implements EnvironmentAware` instead of using `@Autorwired` resolved my issue.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example?